# How to recognize in runtime that we are running on an apk that was downloaded from Amazon

Tags: android, google-play, amazon-appstore

We have an android app which is on google play and on android. We wish to check in runtime if the game has been downloaded from google play or for amazon (for purposes of in-app purchases sdk and also analytics). How can we check it?

Comment: If you have different apks, checking the version is easily. If the apk is same in binary, nothing can be done to check the download source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29) to query from which store the app has been downloaded from.

For Google Play, it returns `com.android.vending`. For Amazon it returns [`com.amazon.venezia`](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3679). Note, if you install it manually (i.e., via adb), it will by default return null. You can use

```
adb shell pm install -i com.myappstore com.example.package
```

To fake any installer you want for testing purposes.

Comment: Would you use that to choose whether to use google play in-app purchases or amazon sdk? Is this method safe?

Comment: Both SDKs have the ability to check whether they are available at runtime (either by attempting to connect and failing or via specific methods) so those are potentially the best source of truth, but if you get either of the mentioned results you can guarantee that you have been installed from those sources (as no one but Google/Amazon can set it to those values).